# An unclickable text <input> with Chrome/Safari

Tags: css, google-chrome, text, input, safari

There's an input text I can't click : the SearchInput on the left in this page:

http://www.wikirouge.0fees.net/

The problem only appears with and Chrome and Safari.
It's a reported bug in Mediawiki, but not in Chrome.

More precisely, the text itself can be clicked, but the "space without text" isn't clickable (and no corresponding cursor).

I scanned the css, but it is not a z-index problem, nor a -webkit-user-select: none.
I can't find the cause and no workaround either.
Please help !

Comment: Trying getting rid of all the thinks on the <input> except for the name, value and id

Comment: check if there are any `user-select: none` or something along those lines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cause seems to be something to do with `#mw_contentwrapper`.

You can fix it by adding `position: relative` to `#mw_portlets`.

I tested this fix in Chrome/Safari/Firefox.

Comment: Very efficient ! Thanks a lot !

Comment: an idea what the cause of the problem was?

Comment: @KaeVerens: No idea, since this was 2 years ago and the site is no longer available. If you have a similar problem, can you link to an example page?

Comment: I do have a similar problem, but am not able to replicate it consistently. It sometimes happens in my www.bizti.me application, but not in any way that I've been able to repeat.